# Isis possible to use dynamic feature modules without Google play

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module

is there possibility to use dynamic feature module or something similar without Google play? All files would be on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can technically, with `reflection`/`plugins`.

1. Build an `API module` for your desired code. (Just of bunch of interfaces in `my_api.jar`
2. Import the `API module` on both your App and plugin(`my_plugin.apk` or something).
3. Implement a `proxy` on your App of the `API`.
4. Implement the `API` in your plugin.
5. App downloads the plugin from the server.
6. App `reflects` the plugin onto the `proxy` using the shared `API`.
7. Use the `proxy` to call functionality that didn't exist when the App was first downloaded.

It may not be the cleanest/best solution but it works.